# How to read space-separated data into a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, file

I have a text file with numbers separated by spaces, such as:

```
-2 -3 4 -1 -2 1.5 -3
```

I tried to create an numpy array with the file elements using the following code:

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()
A = np.array([])
arquivox = filedialog.askopenfilename()
# reading datafile
with open(arquivox, "r") as f:
    for termox in f:
        # specifying the separator
        termox = termox.split(' ')
        # converting the elements to float and generating the array
        A = np.append(A, float(termox[0]))
print(A)
```

However, I am only saving the first element of the file (-2). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well you're only appending the first element... `termox[0]`... Maybe you need something more like `A = np.array([float(x) for x in termox])`

Comment: Here `float(termox[0])` you only take the first element (`0`).

Comment: You have a list of values in `termox`, yet you're only float/appending the first item in that list. You know how to iterate over an iterable (you're doing it earlier with `for termox in f`).

Comment: Oh, the way I was doing it was like I was waiting for the data to be separated by 'enter'. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are reading into a `numpy.array` anyway, I'd suggest using [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

```
import numpy as np
A = np.loadtxt(arquivox, delimiter=' ')
```